# Add button crashes the app

Tags: java, android, button, runtime-error

I am trying to add a simple button to my application but I got the error below:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Here is my Java code:

```
final Button settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Settings.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Here is my XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:src="@drawable/settings"
    android:background="@drawable/settings"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

By the way, this is the second button I have tried to add. The first one worked fine.

Comment: Your findViewById can't find the Button. Please provide code where you inflate your layout and where you set your onClickListener

Comment: I think, there might be an answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32017810/4667038

Comment: need full code then only we can suggest the ans

Comment: @babadaba I think the problem is that I don't use inflate

Comment: You don't need inflate, setContentView will be fine. Is the second button in the same xml file as the first, working one? And of course findViewById has to be called after setContentView

Comment: Show your `Full code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a reference problem. Maybe more than one button with the same ID is present.

To make this easier you can also set the `onClick` attribute in the XML for your button. Here is the code:

**XML:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:src="@drawable/settings"
    android:background="@drawable/settings"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="ButtonClick" />
```

**Java:**

```
public void ButtonClick(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Settings.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that there is not another button or another element with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

just do it like this in your code:

```
class Abc{
Button settings;

   onCreate(..){

    ...
    setContentView(<your xml>);
    ...

    settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Settings.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
   }
}
```

It might be helpful.